# Can constructor chaining be used in place of overloaded constructor

Tags: c#

I have a constructor in my windows forms

```
public frmSecondarySEC(int intPrimaryDocumentId, int intSecondaryDocumentId, string strStateCode, int intCountyId, string strPrimaryDocTypeName, string strPrimaryDocTypeCode, string strDealName, string strLoanNumber, int intDealId, string strDealType, string strCountyName, bool blIsFileReview)
{

}
```

Now i need to pass an extra parameter to this constructor. For this i created an overloaded version of this constructor so that other classes using the original constructor does not break up.Only difference is addition of new parameter.

```
public frmSecondarySEC(int intPrimaryDocumentId, int intSecondaryDocumentId, string    strStateCode, int intCountyId, string strPrimaryDocTypeName, string strPrimaryDocTypeCode, string strDealName, string strLoanNumber, int intDealId, string strDealType, string strCountyName, bool blIsFileReview,string primaryDocumentTitle)
{
}
```

Now since they share commom initialization code, i tried constructor chaining

```
public frmSecondarySEC(int intPrimaryDocumentId, int intSecondaryDocumentId, string strStateCode, int intCountyId, string strPrimaryDocTypeName, string strPrimaryDocTypeCode, string strDealName, string strLoanNumber,int intDealId, string strDealType, string strCountyName, bool blIsFileReview) : this(int intPrimaryDocumentId, int intSecondaryDocumentId, string strStateCode, int intCountyId, string strPrimaryDocTypeName, string strPrimaryDocTypeCode, string strDealName, string strLoanNumber, int intDealId, string strDealType, string strCountyName, bool blIsFileReview)
{
}
```

However I am getting an error on this part

```
:this(int intPrimaryDocumentId
```

which says

Invalid expression term 'int' .Am i using a wrong implementation of constructor chaining or it can be done some other way. I want to prevent duplication of code. Please suggest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It knows the type, just pass the parameter.

```
:this(intPrimaryDocumentId)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call one from the other like so:

```
public M (int k) { }

public M () : this(1) { }
```

So, you don't redefine the variable, you just pass it in as if you are calling a method.

Answer (score 1):

When chaining constructors, you don't specify the types again. It should be:

```
public frmSecondarySEC(int intPrimaryDocumentId, int intSecondaryDocumentId, string strStateCode, int intCountyId, string strPrimaryDocTypeName, string strPrimaryDocTypeCode, string strDealName, string strLoanNumber,int intDealId, string strDealType, string strCountyName, bool blIsFileReview)
    : this(intPrimaryDocumentId, intSecondaryDocumentId, strStateCode, intCountyId, strPrimaryDocTypeName, strPrimaryDocTypeCode, strDealName, strLoanNumber, intDealId, strDealType, strCountyName, blIsFileReview)
```

Also, you should probably consider whether all those parameters are necessary. Seriously.